# Adding price field to magento attribute

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, php, core

I have added a custom field(price) to magento dropdown attribute(see image).[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwi8I.jpg]

I also added a new column to **eav_attribute_option** table and I can pull down the prices I have added manually. As I am new to Magento, how do I go about saving this price to the **eav_attribute_option** table? any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you adding a column to a SQL table? In the screen shot you are adding static prices (i.e. you can add this to a product but it will be for all products)

Answer (score 2):

Always happens, I stumble upon a solution after hitting up SE.

Anyways, the solution lies in overriding Mage/Eav/Model/Resource/Entity/Attribute.php file. In the the _saveOption() method, I copied how sort order was being captured and saved